# How can I look at the log file for details as I get 'permission denied'?

Tags: permissions, log

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 on a HP Pavilion that has Vista home prem. The Broadcom STA driver is listed, tested by the Ubuntu developers, but will not activate and I get a

> look at the log file for details:/var/log/jockey.log

When I try to do so in the terminal I get "Permission denied".

Please help, I already am running 11.10 on a Toshiba Satellite with Vista basic with no problems for a few weeks and really like it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: `gksudo gedit /var/log/jockey.log`? If so and you still get "Permission denied" error, this means that the log file is in use. Try closing jokey. If it still fails to open, open the system monitor and kill the jockey process. Alternatively, press alt + F2 and type "killall jockey".

Comment: Thank you,yes, I got it open, now I'll have to spend some time researching how to understand what I'm seeing and how I can get the driver to work,ha ha ,,cheers.

Comment: OK, cheers! Could you please mark my post as the accepted answer by clicking the green check mark under the down vote button? Thanks.